# How to set firebase real;time database rules according to the data?

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make my chat data private and only accessible by the logged-in user.

I don't have any idea to set the firebase rules.
My data structure looks like follows.

```
{
  "chat" : {
    "-L1223434cI8qG1eLQUyj" : {
      "User" : {
        "_id" : "66b2-4bac-abe1-fe89a0e29a28",
        "name" : "aaaabbbccc"
      },
      "friendID" : "8bcd-4b62-bb4e-25b7c1df4ca2",
      "text" : "hello",
      "timestamp" : 1573113592492
    }
```

I want to compare _id to all the authenticated users I have under my application and want to provide access to the user where only his/her id is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired outcome with the following security rules that make use of the built-in `auth` variable that holds information about the currently logged in user:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chat": {
      "$msg_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this message
        // whose uid must exactly match the value of _id
        ".write": "data.child("User/_id").val() === auth.uid",
        // grants read access to the owner or recipient of this
        // message whose uid must exactly match the saved uids
        ".read": "data.child("User/_id").val() === auth.uid || data.child("friendID").val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend reading the [Securing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) and [User Based Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) documentation for further details which explain the concepts in a better fashion than repeating here.